# rearrange two levels of nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 2 levels of nested arrays. 
The first nested array is: completed. I want to know the sum of the regular and irregular objects.
The second nested array is: Additional Task. I want to copy all the objects in this nested array.

Here is my array:

```
const array = [{
            nature: "Configure DB2",
            date: "2020-04-30",
            details: [{
                firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Red",
                completed: [{
                regular: 1,
                irregular: 2,
                additionalTask: [{
                        job: "copyright",
                        hour: 2  
                }, 
                {
                        job: "copyright",
                        hour: 1
                    }],
                    },
                    {
                regular: 2,
                irregular: 3,
                additionalTask: [{
                        job: "singing",
                        hour: 2
                    },
                {
                        job: "copyright",
                        hour: 4
                    }],
                }],
                 },
                 {
                firstName: "Leo", lastName: "Blue",
                completed: [{
                    regular: 3,
                    irregular: 5,
                    additionalTask: [{
                            job: "cooking",
                            hour: 5
                        },
                    {
                            job: "email",
                            hour: 13
                            }],
                        },
                        {
                    regular: 1,
                    irregular: 2,
                    additionalTask: [{
                            job: "email",
                            hour: 3
                        }, 
                    {
                            job: "reading",
                            hour: 3
                            }],
                    }],
                },
            ]
    }]
```

My desired result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an output that matches your visual -- you'd just need to convert it to the matching HTML to produce your table. I'm also assuming your "first name" is a way of uniquely identifying people.

```js
const array = [{
            nature: "Configure DB2",
            date: "2020-04-30",
            details: [{
                firstName: "Alex",
                completed: [{
                regular: 1,
                irregular: 2,
                additionalTask: [{
                        job: "copyright",
                        hour: 2  
                }, 
                {
                        job: "profread",
                        hour: 1
                    }],
                    },
                    {
                regular: 2,
                irregular: 3,
                additionalTask: [{
                        job: "singing",
                        hour: 2
                    },
                {
                        job: "dancing",
                        hour: 4
                    }],
                }],
                 },
                 {
                firstName: "Leo",
                completed: [{
                    regular: 3,
                    irregular: 5,
                    additionalTask: [{
                            job: "cooking",
                            hour: 5
                        },
                    {
                            job: "email",
                            hour: 13
                            }],
                        },
                        {
                    regular: 1,
                    irregular: 2,
                    additionalTask: [{
                            job: "playing",
                            hour: 3
                        }, 
                    {
                            job: "reading",
                            hour: 3
                            }],
                    }],
                },
            ]
    }];

const output = array.map(top => {
  const items = {};
  top.details.forEach(d => {
    items[d.firstName] = items[d.firstName] || {completed: {
      sumRegular: 0,
      sumIrregular: 0,
    }, additionalTask: {}};
    const p = items[d.firstName];
    (d.completed || []).forEach(c => {
      p.completed.sumRegular += c.regular;
      p.completed.sumIrregular += c.irregular;
      (c.additionalTask || []).forEach(t => {
        p.additionalTask[t.job] = t.hour;
      });
    });
  });
  return items;
});


console.log(output);
```

Comment: By the way, how do I retain the firstName? actual array contains firstName and LastName...

Comment: firstName is already there -- it's the first level of grouping

Comment: My question is how to make...
{firstName: Alex, 
{additionalTask:{copyright: 2, profread: 1, singing: 2, dancing: 4}}, 
completedsumRegular: 3, sumIrregular: 5}}, 

Also:
How to make additional task accept the same values. Right now, if all four tasks are named 'copyright' it results to 
{additionalTask:{copyright: 2}},
my desired result is to accept similar name:
{additionalTask:{copyright: 2, copyright: 5, copyright: 8, reading: 1}},

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to demonstrate, but that is certainly not valid JSON or plain objects for either of your examples. My output matches your desired output exactly.

Comment: I edited my original post. Right now, task name does not allow duplicate. Please make it allow duplicate.